# regex javax.servlet.Filter with Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter

Tags: java, web-applications, servlet-filters, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Can Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) filter requests through additional javax.servlet.Filter's?

The true problem is that web.xml's filter-mapping doesn't allow regex.  I created my own RegexFilter but was wondering if Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter could do this instead.  It would just be nice to keep everything in one place.

For example it would be nice if I could add something like this to urlrewrite.xml:

```
<filter>
    <url-pattern>^/news/([0-9]+)$</url-pattern>
    <filter-class>com.foo.bar.NewsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: FYI... I opened a ticket with Tuckey to see if they can add this. http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/issues/detail?id=129